# Why my Django project is being displayed in subdomain and localhost at the same time?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

The thing is that I have a django project installed in a subdomain in localhost and at the same time I have the localhost for other stuff without Django.

Whenever I access a1.localhost it displays my django welcome page ok, but when I want to access just localhost it also displays the same django welcome page instead of the index.html.

So far this is what I have:

```
Hosts:
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       a1.localhost

vhosts.conf:
#-- a1.localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a1.localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/workspace/website1/apache/django.wsgi"
    <Directory "C:/workspace/website1/apache">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#-- localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/workspace/website1/django_project"
</VirtualHost>


django.wsgi

import os
import sys

path = "C:/workspace/website1/apache/django_project"
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

What I want to achieve is to display my normal index.html file in localhost and my django project in a1.localhost.

Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm confused after looking at the config again.. what's the error log you are getting? Also, did you set `NameVirtualHost *:80` anywhere?

Comment: There is no error actually, what happens is that when I access  localhost instead of displaying index.html it displays my django project that belongs to a1.localhost

Comment: it works when I change the port in the virtual host a1.localhost from 80 to let's say 8080. 
So when I access http://localhost it displays the index.html contents ok & when I access http://a1.localhost:8080 it also displays my django project ok too, but this is what I really want to avoid, I can also use mod_rewrite or mod_proxy, but I want to do  is to work in the same host and avoid all this mod_proxy & extra stuff.

Comment: Odd.. did you set `NameVirtualHost *:80`? What happens if you prepend `<VirtualHost __default__:80>
Deny from all
</VirtualHost>` to the other virtual hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening here is the first virtual host accepts all traffic to port 80 and redirects it to the django app.  The second virtual host is not receiving traffic at all.  The whole thing works when they're different ports, because in that case apache knows which virtualhost should receive the traffic.

You might need to add a line before these declarations to set up the virtualhost naming, as Kay Zhu mentioned:

NameVirtualHost *:80

See this article for more information:
http://digitalpbk.blogspot.com/2007/01/making-subdomains-on-localhost.html